# Snakemake takes forever to create conda envs

Tags: conda, snakemake, virtual-environment, mamba

I am using the `--use-conda` option to create separate environments for some rules. Whether I am using my own yaml files or `snakemake` wrappers that download the relevant yaml file, `snakemake` always gets stuck at creating the first environment:

```
(snakemake) user@computer:.../test$ snakemake --cores 24 --use-conda
Building DAG of jobs...
Removing incomplete Conda environment https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v2.0.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml...
Creating conda environment https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v2.0.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml...
Downloading and installing remote packages.
^CCancelling snakemake on user request. (After 10 minutes nothing happens and I stopped it manually)
```

When I create a new environment manually with `mamba env create --name TEST --file https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake-wrappers/raw/v2.0.0/bio/fastqc/environment.yaml` it runs without any issues and it finishes very quickly.

I am using `snakemake` version 7.32.3.

Why can `snakemake` not make any `conda` environments?

Comment: Are you launching `snakemake` on a head node?

Comment: I am running it on a desktop PC

Comment: I removed the .snakemake directory and now it works